# Externalize Hystrix configuration through application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix

I have a method with hystrix fallback enabled:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackExecute")
public void execute() {
  // some logic goes here
}

public void fallBackExecute() {
  // some fallback logic goes here
}
```

Is there a way to configure the fallback method using properties of hystrix, without using `@HystrixCommand` annotation, to avoid tightly coupling the fallback method in the code.

If anyone have tried similar approach, please share it here.

Thank you.

Comment: There is not a way to do what you want.